# My boolean method java

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I've done quite a bit of searching for an answer to this, and some editing and I cant get it to work.  I think there's something wrong with my boolean method, getColor().  Im trying to use it in a loop from a different class.

herse my getColor method, from the AvatarPanel class

```
    public boolean setColor(boolean good)
{

    if (good == true)
        what--;
        avatars.get(0).setBackground(colors.get(what));
    repaint();
    if (good == false)  
        what++;
        avatars.get(0).setBackground(colors.get(what));
    repaint();

    return good;
}
```

And here's the attackPerformed method from the Background class that Im trying to use getColor in.  Im not sure if I wrote one of the methods wrong, or if attackPerformed needs a listener.  The game is still running normally and working fine. I just wanted some help making sure these were at least written correctly.

I decided it might be a good idea to show the background constructor because I think its where I need to call attackPerformed.  I can't figure out where it is that I need to call the attackPerformed, though I'm pretty sure it'll be in the background constructor. The attackPerformed method is shown below, constructor is at top.

```
public class Background extends JPanel implements Constants, ActionListener
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private final Color BACK_COLOR = Color.GRAY;

   private ArrayList<Sprite> sprites;

   private Avatar avatar;

   /** Constructor  */
   public Background()
   {

       sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
       reset(0);
       setBackground(BACK_COLOR);


       KeyboardFocusManager manager =KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
       manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher()
       {
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
        {
            int x = 0, y = 0;
            double angle = 0;
            Point p = avatar.getPosition();

            switch (event.getKeyCode())
            {
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                y=6;
                angle=270;
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                y = -6;
                angle = 90;
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                x = -6;
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                x = 6;
                angle = 180;
                break;
            }

            avatar.setParameters();
            p.x += x;
            p.y += y;
            avatar.setPosition(p);
            avatar.setAngle(angle);

            if (!getBounds().contains(avatar.getBounds()))
            {
                avatar.restore();
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                return true;
            }
            repaint();
            return true;            
        }



    });
    Timer timer = new Timer(15, this);
    timer.start();



} //end of constructor  



public void attackPerformed()
{
    for(Sprite s : sprites)
    {
        AvatarPanel panel = new AvatarPanel();
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(sprites.get(0).getBounds());
        Rectangle p = new Rectangle(sprites.get(1).getBounds());

            if(r.intersects(p))
            {
                panel.setColor(false);
            }               
    }   
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    for (Sprite s : sprites)
    {
        if (s instanceof Move)
        {
            s.setParameters();
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                ((Move)s).nextPosition();
                if (!getBounds().contains(s.getBounds()))
                {
                    ((Move) s).moveFailed();
                }
                else break;
            }
        }
    }
    repaint();
}




public @Override void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
   super.paintComponent(g); /* Let the parent class do its painting */

   for (Sprite sprite: sprites)
   {
       sprite.draw(g);
   }
 }

public void reset(int level)
{
    Sprite sprite = null;

    int x, y, angle;
    double scale, min, max;

    sprites.clear();
    int[] figures = FIGURES[level];
    for (int f=0; f<figures.length; f++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<figures[f]; i++)
        {
            x = (int)(Math.random()*600 + 100);
            y = (int)(Math.random()*400 + 100);

            switch (f)
            {
                case 0:
                    sprite = avatar = new Avatar(x,y);
                    break;
                case 1:

                    sprite = new Predator(x,y);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sprite = new Mine(x,y);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sprite = new Shield(x,y);
                    break;
            }

            angle = (int)(Math.random()*360);
            sprite.setAngle(angle);

            min = sprite.getMinScaleFactor();
            max = sprite.getMaxScaleFactor();
            scale = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
            sprite.setScale(scale);

            sprites.add(sprite);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you missing some {}s from setColor? When you do an if statement if you're not following that with a block of statements enclosed in {}, it's only going to conditionally run the first statement. So right now, the only thing that's conditional is your what-- and what++ lines. Each time you call setColor, you're doing two setBackground and repaint steps.

Comment: In setColor method, either use correct level of indentation or curly braces.

Comment: Where is the return statement? It seams a part of your setColor method is missing.

Comment: yeah my copy paste on set color must have missed a bracket.

Comment: I fixed my copy paste on setColor to show return

Comment: my setBackground does not have a paint method in it though so I think it needs to be changed to the color provided by set color, and then painted.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your if and else case are very similar. 
You can simplify it to this.

```
public boolean setColor(boolean good)
{
    what+=good?-1:+1;
    avatars.get(0).setBackground(colors.get(what));
    repaint();
    return good;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend to use brackets, as the method repaint() would execute outside of if statement. Since, boolean can only have two possible values you can use 'else' instead of second if...

```
public boolean setColor(boolean good)
{
    if (good == true)
    {
        what--;
        avatars.get(0).setBackground(colors.get(what));
        repaint();
    }
    else 
    {    
        what++;
        avatars.get(0).setBackground(colors.get(what));
        repaint();
    }
```